# How to remove limit on core dump file size

Tags: 12.10, settings, ulimit

I would like to increase the maximum size limit for core dump files as a regular user. Using `bash`, I can set it like this:

```
$ ulimit -c 100
```

which works well the first time I set it.
However, the next time I use this command, I can only set this limit to a value not exceeding 100.
In general, I can set it to an arbitrary value only the first time I use this command since login.
All the next times, the possible values are limited from above by the initially set value.

How can I make this persistent across multiple uses of the command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [@Peter Bašista](https://askubuntu.com/users/32956/peter-ba%c5%a1ista)'s answer in his own question:

> At first, I thought this is an error and that's why I started this
>   question. But it turned out it's simply a perfectly correct behavior.
>   It turns out that RTFM saying applies here as well.
>
> As `man bash` reveals, the `ulimit` built-in command has additional
>   parameters: `-H` for setting the so-called **hard** limits and `-S`
>   for setting the so-called **soft** limits. Moreover, if none of these
>   options are given, the default behavior is that `ulimit` tries to set
>   **both** the soft and the hard limits to the same value at once. And that was the problem.
>
> Now there is a quote from the `bash` man page:
>
> > A hard limit cannot be increased  by a non-root user once it is set;
>
> So, there we go. The correct usage of `ulimit` command should always
>   have this in mind. Most importantly, it should never be used without
>   `-H` or `-S` options unless you are sure to know what you are doing
>   (which at the time I obviously wasn't).
>
> What I should have done is something like this:
>
> After login: `ulimit -H -c unlimited`
>
> Each time I want to change maximum core dump size limit `ulimit -S -c
>   <new size>`
>
> So, that's about it. I hope it could help someone who might struggle
>   with a similar problem.