# Catching runaway processes

Tags: process, productivity

Occassionally, I run a command that hogs RAM and brings my system to a grind. Even pressing `Ctrl-C` takes 20 minutes to register, because the system is busy swapping to disk.

What solutions are available?

I have some ideas, but don't know exact solutions:

1. Give maximum priority to the window-manager and system processes, while giving a lower priority to all other processes.
2. Run a watch-dog process with highest priority that watches for runaway process behaviour. I remember KDE used to have such a tool couple of years back. Is there a modern (GNOME/Unity) equivalent?

Comment: How about using `Ctrl + \ ` in place of `Ctrl + c`?

Comment: @Jobin what does that do?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14155/what-to-do-when-ctrl-c-wont-kill-running-job).

Comment: @Jobin Ah thanks. I didn't know about it. But in my case, the process is responding to Ctrl-c, but the system itself has slowed down, and the Ctrl-c reaches the process very slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Read `man bash` or `info bash` and check out the `ulimit` bash command. It will let you limit your processes in many ways.

Also see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220905/how-to-remove-limit-on-core-dump-file-size) about Hard and Soft ulimits.