# Ubuntu 15.04 Crashes while viewing media in a web browser

Tags: crash

The system crashes usually when I am watching a youtube video or viewing a twitch stream. I haven't got any crash logs because the standard logs cant catch any information. and I ran into a problem with apport-retrace so I cant view the logs generated by crash dump.

My system is a Dell Inspiron i3541 and the error I keep running into with apport retrace is:

```
Invalid core dump: BFD: Warning: /tmp/apport_core_DUCsQ1 is truncated: expected core file size >= 219979776, found: 208732160.
```

I'd like to think that flash player is the culprit but I have no idea what the flash package is named. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Mybe helpful: http://askubuntu.com/q/220905/367165